# folium map not refreshing data on map and displaying previous data visualizations

Tags: python, dictionary, visualization, render, folium

I have used folium library to create a map `Stamen Toner` and it worked great.but when I try to refresh the data to visualize other result it keep showing the previous result.

```html
from flask import Flask, request, render_template,make_response,Response
import io
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from flask_googlemaps import GoogleMaps
from flask_googlemaps import Map,icons
import folium


app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path = "/tmp", static_folder = "tmp")



@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template('myform.html')



@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def my_form_post():
    text = request.form['search']
    #processed_text = text.upper()
    df = pd.read_csv('func_latest.csv',engine='python')
    #df1 = df[(df.topic == text)]
    df['topic'] = df['topic'].str.lower()
    words=text.split(" ")
    print(words)

    df1=df[df.topic.str.contains(text)==True]
    print(df1)


    map = folium.Map(location=[0, 0], zoom_start=2, tiles='Stamen Toner')
    def color(contry):
        col = ''
        df = df1
        print(df)
        score = 0
        for row in df.itertuples():
            if row.country == contry:
                score = score + row.sentiment
                if score == 0:
                    col = 'darkblue'
                if score > 0:
                    col = 'green'
                if score < 0:
                    col = 'darkred'
        return col

    map.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open('world_geojson_from_ogr.json', encoding="utf-8-sig").read(),
                                 name="Population",
                                 style_function=lambda x: {
                                     'fillColor': color(x['properties']['NAME']) if x['properties'][
                                                                                        'NAME'] == 'Pakistan'
                                     else color(x['properties']['NAME']) if x['properties']['NAME'] == 'India'
                                     else color(x['properties']['NAME']) if x['properties']['NAME'] == 'China'
                                     else color(x['properties']['NAME']) if x['properties']['NAME'] == 'United States'
                                     else color(x['properties']['NAME']) if x['properties']['NAME'] == 'United Kingdom'
                                     else 'white'}))
    map.add_child(folium.LayerControl())

    map.save(outfile='C:/Users/LENOVO_PC/PycharmProjects/untitled1/templates/map.html')
    return render_template('map.html')

import os
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if os.path.exists("map.html"):
        os.remove("map.html")
    app.run()
```

This is showing the updated result in console but it is not refreshing the Map and showing the updated visualizations of sentiments on Map.
[Folium map visualization at first glance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VZdR.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
Flask does not by default refresh templates . You can set

```
app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
```

where you define the flask app

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

details can be found here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/